# valid code in /etc/crontab won't be executed

Tags: cron

In a minimal, non customized Ubuntu 16.04 server system, my /etc/crontab has the following code, which executes fine when executed manually:

```
0 8 * * * zip -r /UsualUser/backups/dirs/html-$(date +\%F-\%T-).zip /var/www/html
0 8 * * * find /UsualUser/backups/dirs/* -mtime +30 -exec rm {} \;
# m h dom m dow
# 0-59 | 0-23 | 1-31 | 1-12 | 0-6
```

No errors in `journalctl -u cron`.

I believe the problem is because the file isn't executable as its permissions are `644`. Yet I'm not sure what is the safest set of permissions to make it executable so the code in it will start to work.

Comment: you should either redirect output to a file or have it mail to you (using MAILTO=me@...) to see what's actually happening.

Comment: 0 8 * * * zip -r ... > /var/tmp/zip.log

Comment: what do you have in syslog? `grep CRON /var/log/syslog` I think you need to type username before commands. Also you can make .sh script and give only path for it in cron file.

Comment: I didn't notice **/etc/crontab** you shouldn't (as a rule) use it for user data, just edit your own crontab file with `crontab -e`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `/etc/crontab` file on Ubuntu is the system crontab file.  It should not be executable and its format is different from a user's crontab file.

The difference in format is that its 6th field is the name of the user that the entry should be executed as.

Also, `%` has a special meaning in crontab files. All `%` will be changed to a newline unless escaped as `\%` (but I see that you have taken precautions against that already).

These things are described in the crontab manual (`man 5 crontab`):

> The  format of a cron command is very much the V7 standard, with a number
>          of upward-compatible extensions.   Each  line  has  five  time  and  date
>          fields,  followed  by  a command, followed by a newline character (`\n`).
>          **The system crontab (`/etc/crontab`) uses the same format, except  that  the
>          username  for the command is specified after the time and date fields and
>          before the command.**

Comment: @Benia Just add a username in front of the command in the system crontab file. This will be the user that the job is executed as.